# How to append dictionaries to an array or dictionary key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I am working on a project that maps teachers to classes and class information. I am using javaScript.

I have my dictionary set up as so:

```
{ Instructor: 'Gondree, Mark',
Class: 'CS 349',
Section: '001',
Components: [ 'ACT' ],
Title: 'Problem Solving in a Team Envn',
WTU: 1.3,
Units: '1',
Meeting_Days: 'F',
Time: '10:00:00 - 11:50:00',
Room: 'STEV1034',
Enrollment: 22,
FTE: 1.47 }
```

I have a bunch of these with different instructors. The problem I am having is using the Instructor to group them into a dictionary or an array. My ideal output is:

```
{
MARK GONDREE{
{ Instructor: 'Gondree, Mark',
Class: 'CS 349',
Section: '001',
Components: [ 'ACT' ],
Title: 'Problem Solving in a Team Envn',
WTU: 1.3,
Units: '1',
Meeting_Days: 'F',
Time: '10:00:00 - 11:50:00',
Room: 'STEV1034',
Enrollment: 22,
FTE: 1.47 },
ANOTHER CLASS HERE

GLEN CARTER{
{ Instructor: 'Carter, Glenn',
Class: 'CS 101',
Section: '018',
Components: [ 'DIS', 'ACT' ],
Title: 'Intro Computers & Computing',
WTU: 1.3,
Units: '3',
Meeting_Days: 'W',
Time: '10:00:00 - 11:50:00',
Room: 'DARW0024',
Enrollment: 14,
FTE: 2.8 },
ANOTHER CLASS HERE
}
```

I essentially have all the class info and instructors in order by name but I just need to group them. Do you have any advice on whether to use an array or a dictionary? Also, would it be possible to append a class to the dictionary or array a certain instructor?

Comment: Your ideal output is not a valid structure. Since you want to group by instructor, and instructors may have one or more classes associated with them, you will need to use an array of objects for each instructor. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the objects in a `Map` and use `Map.get(<instructor name>)` to get the corresponding object and `Map.set()` to set or modify the object.

```js
const data = [{"Instructor":"Gondree, Mark","Class":"CS 349","Section":"001","Components":["ACT"],"Title":"Problem Solving in a Team Envn","WTU":1.3,"Units":"1","Meeting_Days":"F","Time":"10:00:00 - 11:50:00","Room":"STEV1034","Enrollment":22,"FTE":1.47}];

const formatEntry = entry => 
  [
    entry.Instructor // get `Instructor` property value
    .toUpperCase() // convert to uppercase
    .match(/[A-Z]+/ig) // match only letters, omitting space and comma
    .reverse() // reverse original entry format of name `'Gondree, Mark'`
    .join(' ') // join name array with space character
  , entry // original plain object `entry` 
  ];

const instructors = new Map(data.map(formatEntry)); // enter initial entry
// set new entry
instructors.set(
  ...formatEntry({"Instructor":"Carter, Glenn","Class":"CS 101","Section":"018","Components":["DIS","ACT"],"Title":"Intro Computers & Computing","WTU":1.3,"Units":"3","Meeting_Days":"W","Time":"10:00:00 - 11:50:00","Room":"DARW0024","Enrollment":14,"FTE":2.8})
);
// get entries
console.log(
  instructors.get('MARK GONDREE')
, instructors.get('GLENN CARTER')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create an array of objects like this:

```
let instructors = [
    { Instructor: 'Gondree, Mark', Class: 'CS 349', Section: '001', Components: [ 'ACT' ], Title: 'Problem Solving in a Team Envn', WTU: 1.3, Units: '1', Meeting_Days: 'F', Time: '10:00:00 - 11:50:00', Room: 'STEV1034', Enrollment: 22, FTE: 1.47 },
    { Instructor: 'Carter, Glenn', Class: 'CS 101', Section: '018', Components: [ 'DIS', 'ACT' ], Title: 'Intro Computers & Computing', WTU: 1.3, Units: '3', Meeting_Days: 'W', Time: '10:00:00 - 11:50:00', Room: 'DARW0024', Enrollment: 14, FTE: 2.8 },
    { Instructor: 'Gondree, Mark', Class: 'CS 349', Section: '001', Components: [ 'ACT' ], Title: 'Problem Solving in a Team Envn', WTU: 1.3, Units: '1', Meeting_Days: 'F', Time: '10:00:00 - 11:50:00', Room: 'STEV1034', Enrollment: 22, FTE: 1.47 }
];

console.log(instructors[0].Instructor);
> Gondree, Mark
```

Answer (score 1):

use map on the array (arr stands for original array) of objects and create new array of objects after deleting 'x.Instructor'

```
let new_arr = arr.map(x => ({
    [x.Instructor]: (() => {
        delete x.Instructor;
        return x;
    })()
}))
console.log('arr :', arr);
console.log('new_arr :', new_arr);
```